# Sci-fi horror movie with sentient goop, reasonably recent

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

For the longest time I've failed to remember the name of a movie, which was definitely released post-2000. I think the main character had a buzz cut, and it opened either on a military base or in a prison, from where the main character and one (possibly a few more) are teleported somewhere for duty/serving their sentence through work. If I don't remember this incorrectly, the teleportation is preceded by some alarm going off, and is carried out by some sort of small device they put on their persons, maybe a necklace-type thing.

The work in question is to investigate a research station that has gone dark. From there on the common horror tropes of people getting killed one by one ensues, though the details elude my memory. However, I do remember that towards the end it is revealed that some kind of sentient slime was behind it all; it kind of possessed people and made them do its bidding. I think the main character was the only survivor by the end, and reached a truce by simply convincing the slime that he was no threat and asked it to stop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice, detailed question!  Just in case there's anything else we can help you remember, you should look at the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407), including things like where you saw it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the movie you're thinking of is [*Infini*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3327624/), released in 2015.

> I think the main character had a buzz cut

The main character has a close cropped hair style.

> it opened either on a military base or in a prison

The main action takes place on board a mining station, but also at a Search & Rescue base on Earth.

> [they].. are teleported somewhere

They travel using a form of teleportation called "slipstream"

> some kind of sentient slime

"the planet is entirely composed of alien organic material that when thawed forms a so-called "primordial ooze"" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infini))